# Trouble connecting to LG phone with adb (Mac OS X 10.7.5)

Tags: android, macos, usb, adb, lg

When I run `adb devices` there are no devices showing as connected. My device is a LG Optimus Exceed 2 running 4.4.2
There are many of these posts around, so here's what I've done:

- I'm using the cord that came with the phone. It charges and tries to sync photos, so it isn't an issue here. Switching usb ports and trying a powered usb hub doesn't affect it either.
- I've added the vendor id (0x1004) to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
- Restarted and unplugged any combination of things you can think of
- USB Debugging is on. And has been restarted. Same with Unknown sources.
- I have never used EasyTether, nor is it installed anywhere on my computer.
- Updated adb, updated my sdk.
- Restarted adb server
- Tried installing LG's drivers: http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-VS450PP (They say they don't support Mac S/W upgrade, yet they have a package to install. No help there)
- I have a Nexus S running 4.1 that works, and an old LG phone running Gingerbread that connect.

Any wizards out there who've already struggled with this who have advice?

Comment: What does `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` show?

Comment: On my LG Spirit 4G, Android Version 5.0.1, I had to enable `Tethering & networks => USB tethering` additional to `Developer options => USB debugging`.

Unfortunately you need to re-enable `Tethering & networks => USB tethering` every time you un/plug your device. 

An `adb kill-server; adb start-server` might also be necessary. No need to add vendor ID (0x1004) to `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` tho.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I tried all of the connection types (charge, MTP, PTP) but perhaps not "Internet Connnection, modem"? You can change it by pulling down the system-wide drop down menu and touching "USB connection".

This is how I fixed it, but I thought I'd tried this already, so I can't guarantee it wasn't this in conjunction with one of the things done above.

Comment: If this is meant to be an answer, please re-write it to explicitly state the action which resolved the problem.

Comment: Helped too. HTC ID 1004:6300 LG Electronics, Inc. under Linux Mint

Comment: I feel like I've tried everything imaginable, then I find your post. Turns out the only thing I didn't do was try connecting using "Internet Connection". It works! Many thanks! (For the record, I selected "Ethernet" instead of "Modem" and it still worked.)

Comment: Pulling my hair out over this until I came across this, the one connection type I didn't try. Good stuff.

Comment: For Optimus Exceed 2 (LG-VS450PP), PTP does not worked but Internet Connection-Modem worked.

Comment: LG Spirit 4G requires you to go to `Settings` -> `Tethering & networks` -> switch on `USB tethering`

Comment: I have no pop-up on the universal menu, a@fj.by suggestions ?

Comment: This is hilarious.

Answer (score 21):

PTP seemed to do the trick. Never had to do that on any other device...

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same problem. Selectin Internet Connection and then Ethernet as the USB connection type fixed it and everything is working as expected now.

Answer (score 4):

I know this sounds like a stupid answer, but the same thing happened to me. It turns out the micro USB cord was just bad - which is weird, because it still charged the phone perfectly fine. After testing the bad cable unsuccessfully on a phone that had been recognized on my mac before, I switched to a different micro USB cable, and that made all the difference.

Comment: That's not a stupid answer. Some cords can only charge and cannot transfer data.

Answer (score 0):

This is late in the game but I had an additional step to all the other suggestions. The phone was showing up in the System Profiler after I switched the usb mode to 'MTP' mode, but I didn't see any usb tethering options. After adding the phone's vendor ID to the usb ini file, enabling the developer and usb debugging, killing and restarting adb, I still didn't see my device in adb devices.

I finally had to download the Mac driver for the phone directly from LG.com. After installing and rebooting on the computer, the device showed up in adb devices.