# LG Device Not Listed in ADB Devices

Tags: android, linux, macos, adb, lg

This is similar to the question already asked here:

[Trouble connecting to LG phone with adb (Mac OS X 10.7.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434850/trouble-connecting-to-lg-phone-with-adb-mac-os-x-10-7-5)

But it does not seem to be resolved and I have a few additional details.
I am attempting to connect a Verizon LG Optimus Exceed 2 to install an apk and debug, but it will not appear in the list when checking adb devices or running the device monitor. I have tried on both my Mac and Linux systems and the result is the same.

Developer options and USB debugging are enabled, and I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 that works perfectly fine running the same version of the OS (4.4.2). On Linux I created a udev rules file, but unsurprisingly this did not resolve the issue since it doesn't appear as a permissions issue, it just doesn't seem to find the device at all. It does however appear as an attached device in the file system, labeled "LGE Android Phone," and I can view its internal storage.

Any suggestions how to get adb to recognize the phone?

Comment: Same problem but no luck for me.... my LG G2/Optimus phone is 1004:631e or 631c (I don't know why the product ID sometimes varies).  I can read pictures from the photos directory, so the cable's data should be OK.  But it's just not recognized by ADB.  Tried all the tips I could find online.

Answer (score 63):

The problem is with the "do you trust this computer" dialog not being shown.

On LG Spirit 4G, the solution is as follows:

- Ensure the developer menu is enabled (through `About phone` -> `Software info` -> keep tapping `Builder number`)
- Ensure USB debugging is enabled in the developer menu
- Go to `Settings` -> `Tethering & networks` -> switch on `USB tethering`

This will finally trigger the "do you trust this computer" dialog and enable USB debugging.

Addendum: After your device is disconnected, the issue might appear again  because `USB tethering` is automatically disabled.

Comment: I'd NEVER have found this solution on my own. Not a single reason to use usb tethering. <edit> Well that worked... once.

Comment: @kaay After your device is disconnected, the issue might appear again  because `USB tethering` is automatically disabled. I've edited my answer for this.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Sprint model, but on Verizon this can also be achieved in Charging-only mode. When I was in "File Transfer" or "System Update" modes, ADB wouldn't detect the device.

Comment: I'm having this exact situation in a computer here. It was working just fine a week ago. Now `adb devices` won't show my LG V20 unless I turn on USB tethering. What changed? Edit: turning off file transfer on the phone fixed it...

Comment: WOW.  This just worked with a brand new LG Phone in 2021 (LG Velvet) -- I've NEVER had to do this for ANY android device, not once.  WTF LG.

Comment: USB tethering does not work without a SIM card

Answer (score 10):

Well, not sure if the OP is still looking for the answer.
I happen to run into the same situation with Mac OS Yosemite and LG Optimus Exceed 2.

I did add the vendor ID to dab_usb.ini file, however, it still doesn't work.
I also installed LG driver downloaded from LG website, still no good.

Finally, I switch the PC connection to "Internet connection" > ethernet. Then, it finally shows up in adb devices !!!

Comment: I ran into this problem today and this solution works.

Comment: Where did you change this setting?

Comment: I don't have that phone any more, but I think it should be in the setting. There is a place you can switch to different type of connections.

Comment: On my LG device (Android 7), This is under Developer Options > Select USB Configuration > RNDIS (USB Ethernet).  After revoking authorizations and installing drivers, the device is recognized!

Answer (score 3):

This is valid for any device that is not in the ID Vendor in Android Studio or Eclipse and you want to connect to debugging in OS X:

1) Go to Terminal and then:

```
cd ~

cd ./.android
```

2) Edit the `adb_usb.ini`
You should use vim instead of textedit.

```
vim adb_usb.ini
```

Some text to edit appears:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
```

¡¡Insert here the line with the ID Vendor!!
The ID Vendor is in About this Mac - system information - USB (have the device to be connected)

3) Go to the path:

```
cd <where you have the sdk, be careful if you are using Eclipse or Android Studio>/platform-tools
```

Then, export to the bash:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
```

Then:

```
sudo adb kill-server

sudo adb start-server

adb devices
```

4) Run Android Studio, and in the DDMS, your device is detected. Then allow permissions in the device.

5) Start debugging, enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I could not find the `Tethering` option @Ken Van Hoeylandt mentions (language issue most likely), so rather than change the phone language, I noticed that when switching from `File transfer` to `Charging` in the `USB options` (located in `Settings` or in the drop-down menu), the prompt to "trust this computer" came up. Device used is an LG K40.

Answer (score 1):

Changing USB mode from MTP to any other mode works, which is because it reports different device id that can be supported by google's android adb driver. If you want to have adb support for MTP mode, then LG's official driver should be installed.

Comment: Thanks, I found the drivers here:  https://gsmusbdriver.com/lg-wing-5g

Answer (score 0):

I am using an LG Wing.  To get this to work I had to change the setting of what the USB connection was for from File Transfer to Photo Transfer to get it to start showing up in the adb devices list.