# Get Android ADB running with an LG3

Tags: android, adb, lg

I'm trying to get "adb devices" working on either Windows 10 or Ubuntu 17.04. On both operation systems everything is configured for adb to work. A Honor 5X works on both machines as expected.

But no luck with the LGs. I have a few of them for testing, but not a single one is working with adb.

The Version of the Android Debug Bridge is 1.0.39.
The LG is running Android 5.0 Kernel-Version 3.4.0
The Honor 5X is running Android 6.0.1 Kernel Version 3.10.49-g91e5af6

The strange thing about the LGs behaviour is, that in the Notification Area it says, that USB Debugging is enabled but it never asked for authorization. Even when I clear all authorizations it does not ask me for it.

And a "adb devices" does not show the LGs as unauthorized but instead does not show the at all.

That is something all other Smartphones of different brands I tested did consistently.

Accessing the LGs via MTP does work.

I currently do not have an idea how to analyze this any further. I would appreciate any suggestion directing me towards a solution.

Edit: I'm using the adb commandline version.

Edit: This solution (activate USB Tethering) made it better, but this is disabled every time the usb connection is removed and I need a permanent solution working without user interaction.

See [LG Device Not Listed in ADB Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685768/lg-device-not-listed-in-adb-devices?rq=1).

Edit: In Windows 10 I got this working these USB Drivers:
http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-LGD850

But I need to get it working on ubuntu 17.04

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you trying to use ABD via command line/terminal, or are you having problems with your IDE accessing ADB?

Comment: I'm using the command line tools

Comment: What response (if any) are you getting when you try to connect?

Comment: None on the computer. LG beeps and displays that usb debugging is activated. But the device is not found.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I don't know then. Quite possibly some faulty hardware?

Comment: I have tried several LG G3 and not a single one worked. In contrast a Honor 5X and a Samsung worked out out the box on the same computer with the same cable on the same usb port.

Comment: Then it sounds like a specific hardware issue with those LG devices. Are the correct drivers installed?

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of smart phone. I changed the cable and it worked.
(use a thicker cable)

Comment: change the usb port, connect to another port.

Comment: I have already tried it on two different computers with different os. It think it is not the physical connection.

Comment: did you install the lg driver?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself to get it working on Ubuntu 17.04. It is necessary, that you select PTP instead of MTP. This seems to be an specific issue when the LG USB Drivers are not installed, which is never the case in Linux because there LG does not provide any drivers.

Comment: The MTP problem on linux is due (at least for my phone) to LG's MTP having two configuration modes (see lsusb -v) and linux choosing the wrong one.  For those that happen to have the exact problem I had, it is possible to change the configuration (I used pyusb's set_configuration) to regain adb access if you foolishly set an old LG phone with a non-functional screen into MTP mode through scrcpy, thereby locking yourself out.  Changing the configuration also made MTP actually work to transfer files for me.